# How are Google searches from home are showing up on my work computer?

Tags: google-search

I search for something on my home computer. Then I go to work (where I have never used my home computer), and those previous home searches show up on my work computer.

Two devices that have never been connected. I seriously do not want this to happen as you can all imagine. Work and home should be forever separate.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you using same google profile in both cases?

Comment: goto history.google.com from both the machines and see if they are under same profile..

Comment: It sounds like you are syncing the browser.

Comment: Did you login to google chrome the windows/mac/linux software using your google account then forget about it weeks or months later? Google Chrome has a feature called profiles, where not only are profiles stored according to the user account on your computer you use to login to windows/mac/linux, but also the online google account you use to login to the chrome web browser.

Answer (score 1):

How can I prevent this from happening?

A: sign out of your private google account on your work computer and maybe work mobile devices (does your work use gmail as the email service with your work.com domain? that might explain a little bit too...check with IT) You may not know how to sign in or out of gmail accounts in your browser, pls ask if you need to!  :-)

Create a separate gmail account, and use THAT to sign into work stuff.
Using the work gmail account only for work "will prevent this from happening."
Of course, add the good stuff MichaelBay said too.